# CORS policy is allowed in app.py but still not working

Tags: reactjs, flask, python-3.8

The front-end app is built on ReactJs and development server is running on http://localhost:3000. The back-end API is built with Flask 2.0.2 and is running on http://localhost:5000

In app.py file, the CORS has been allowed as mentioned in the [documentation](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) like:

```
CORS(app, resources={r"*": {"origins": "*"}})
```

When I try to submit the login form I still get the following error:

[image]

Comment: You're getting a 500 Internal Server error. The lack of CORS headers is a side effect of your real error. Deal with the actual error report from the server side code.

Answer (score 0):

if you Enables CORS on your backend api , it should work.
I don't think this is an issue with your react frontend application.

cors is a security measure put in by browsers.

You could bypass the Cross-Origin-Policy with chrome extension but it's not advisable -
Try this on your backend API:

- Ensure you have flask cors installed
- create a configuration dictionary like this
- api_v1_cors_config = {
  "origins": ["http://localhost:5000"]
  }

You can then set a global cors for your app like this

- CORS(app, resources={"/api/v1/*": api_v1_cors_config})

// this would allow all methods, origins